# update column with incremented value based on each where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I like to update each row with incremented value based on the where condition.

*exp: select ClientId from [Document] Where ClientId 10*  Shows 3 result then I need to update each matterID with 1 to 3.

1 clientId has one or many MatterID so Need to update each matterID based on number of matterID for each client. IF client 10 holds 3 matterID then matterIDs would be 1 - 2 - 3

Not: It is not updating correctly I am getting matterIDs for this example ramdom number not 1-39-39.

> Stored Procedure

```
    Alter PROCEDURE dbo.CustomIdProcedure 
    @clientId varchar(255) = ''
    AS 

    Begin           
            update e set MatterId = rn  from (select * ,rn=row_number() over (order by id) from [Document] where ClientId  = @clientId ) e
    END
```

**

> To run the Procedure

**
    exec CustomIdProcedure (select ClientId from [Document] Where ClientId <>'')

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery or updatable CTE for this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by clientid order by id) as rn
      from [Document] d
      where ClientId = @clientid
     )
update toupdate
    set MatterId = rn;
```

Comment: how Do you pass @clientid

Comment: I need to pass clientId also for each result one clientId has one or many matterID

Comment: @user2577665 . . . This would be the query inside the stored procedure.

Comment: Not update correctly i am getting matterIDs for this example ramdom number not 1-39-39.

Comment: @user2577665 . . . You can just run the select query separately.  I find it hard to imagine how you could not get numbers from 1-39, assuming there are 39 matching records for the client you are looking at.